# 'Google Play Services is not working'

Tags: google, services

i recently flashed my Samsung Galaxy S4 with Resurrection Remix rom.My phone now doesnt support any of the official Google apps.Whenever i open any such app, it says that 'Google Play Services is not working'

Comment: Have you flashed the latest GApps? Try updating Google Play Services after that.

Answer (score 0):

With some custom roms, the default Google play suite won't work. Check too see if anyone has released a Google play package for that rom.